# Unix Fork Strange Behavior

Tags: c, unix, fork

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int function(void* dat){
    sleep(5);
    printf("Executed Child Process...\n");
    return 5;
}

void dupliFork(int *childpid, int *funcRet, int *func(void*), void* data){
    int id = fork();
    if(id==0) *funcRet = *func(data);
    else *childpid=id;
    printf("Returned dupliFork with id %d\n", id);
}

int main(void){
    int childpid=0, funcRet=0;
    dupliFork(&childpid, &funcRet, function, NULL);
    printf("Waiting for Child Process with id %d...\n", childpid);
    waitpid(childpid, NULL, 0);
    printf("Child Process Terminated with return value %d...\n", funcRet);
}
```

Hello, I'm having trouble understanding how the above code works...
When the code above is executed, I'm getting the output:

```
Returned dupliFork with id 4941
Waiting for Child Process with id 4941...
Executed Child Process...
Child Process Terminated with return value 0..."
```

This is very frustrating, as I was expecting the following output:

```
Returned dupliFork with id 4941
Waiting for Child Process with id 4941...
Executed Child Process...
Returned dupliFork with id 0
Child Process Terminated with return value 5...
```

This is frustrating because it seems that after the fork,
the original duplifork function works perfectly.
However, the copy of it, which calls another function,
and needs the return value to continue its execution, 
never actually behaves that way.
Could someone please explain to me what is actually 
going on here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Er... Why are you passing a `int (void*)` argument `function` for a `int *(void*)` parameter `func`? The compiler must have emitted a diagnostic message about this error. Did you just ignore it? And then in the code you attempt to dereference a "pointer" `func(data)` which is not really a pointer. This would normally crash one of your processes.

Comment: Thank you for a quick and precise answer. I've identified my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function pointer syntax is wrong.

```
int *func(void*)
```

should be:

```
int (*func)(void*)
```

and:

```
if(id==0) *funcRet = *func(data);
```

should be:

```
if(id==0) *funcRet = func(data);
```

Make those changes, and you'll get something resembling:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$ ./fork
Returned dupliFork with id 69707
Waiting for Child Process with id 69707...
Executed Child Process...
Returned dupliFork with id 0
Waiting for Child Process with id 0...
Child Process Terminated with return value 5...
Child Process Terminated with return value 0...
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$
```

since you also (probably erroneously) have the child process `wait()` in addition to the parent.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was looking the wrong way and missed something so obvious... Curious however, no compiler complains about this...

Comment: You probably need to turn your warning level up. Any sane compiler will complain about this. Mine (clang) did.